# Compute difference between two images in EmguCv

Tags: c#, emgucv

Is there a way to find a percentage difference between two images by any distance based on objects in the image in EmguCV? Found a lot of C++ code but not C#.

Answer (score 0):

@Vesper Lynd, finding the percent difference between two images is relatively simple, what I am afraid I am not getting is ***by any distance based*** so if you could tell me what you mean, I may be able to help.

Doug

Comment: saying distance I mean a function that calculates the difference between items. I need something like Jaccard index or Sørensen–Dice coefficient. Sorry, seems in English it's called statistic?